# Tableau tool to generate list of parent and child tables though API

Tags: api, extract, tableau-api

I need to get the list of parent tables with the corresponding child tables in Tableau through API call. Parent tables are basically the tables without any foreign key associated with it. Child tables are the one where the foreign key (primary key of master table is associated with it)

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve parent and child tables from the Tableau Server repository?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the parent and child tables for any given database (Ex: Oracle, MySql ,etc ) through Data extract API (programmatically). Also I want to know if Tableau can show the parent-child tables in a hierarchical way. Main objective is to avoid using queries and let Tableau generate these list of Parent and child Tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. The Tableau Data Extract API doesn't provide methods to discover parent and child tables. The basic principle is that the user defines the structure of the data that is being retrieved, and then the API converts the data into a Tableau Data Extract file (.tde).

To elaborate further, none of the Tableau APIs are designed to allow you to interact with data sources in the way that is required.

- Data Extract API - provides a programmatic way of creating Tableau Data Extracts
- Javascript API - provides a way of interacting with embedded workbooks
- REST API - provides a way of interacting with Tableau Server's metadata (eg: users, projects, workbooks etc)

Comment: Thanks Talvalin for the reply. Sorry i am a newbie to Tableau , would like to know few more details. So does that mean i can't do it programmatically (through Data Extract API , Javascript API , REST API ) to retrieve parent-child tables in Tableau ?

Comment: Thanks @Talvalin for the clear explanation. I would like to know if there is any other tool which helps in getting the parent-child tables programmatically. Like IBM Data Studio ,etc.

Comment: That would be a different question to ask, and possibly one for Super User rather than SO since you're asking for tool advice versus asking a question about a specific coding issue

Comment: Thanks !!! Sorry one last question before i windup. Can we connect to Database (ex:oracle, MySql) and write Custom SQL queries through Data Extract API (or any other API) in Tableau and get the results.

Comment: The Data Extract API is only concerned with creating an extract. How you retrieve the data to be put into the extract is entirely up to you. The other APIs do not relate to connecting to actual data sources, as listed above.

Comment: You can do this as we have done this! You don't need any extra tools at all, just some knowledge around PostgreSQL

Comment: Could you please let me know how you did it